# When does it make sense to build an index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

When does it make sense to build an index in mongodb?

An example from the mLab Slow Query Analyzer:

```
Log lines read
8 hours of logs starting at 2019-02-14 12:25 (2019-02-14 11:25 UTC)

find command
{"myArray":{"$all":["<vals>"]},"myBoolean":{"$ne":"<val>"}}

sort
{"myDate":-1}

total time (all occurrences)
5 seconds, 127 milliseconds

average time
394 milliseconds

query count
13

average documents / index keys examined
50,000 / 50,000

in-memory sort
yes

recommended index
index: {"myDate": -1, "myArray": 1, "myBoolean": 1}
```

A bad performing query, goes through all documents and even sorts in-memory. However the query occurred only 13 times within 8 hours, taking 5 seconds total time.

What are the parameters and values when it does make sense to build an index, e.g. how many % of time of the 8 hours of logs analyzed can a query take until an index should be built?

Comment: Depends. What's the average RPM for your app? 5 and your db hosting is underpowered? You can tolerate an occasional 5 second query. 50000? Best build the index.

Comment: The DB currently does 300 operations per second on average = 8.64M operations in 8 hours. So 0.00015% of operations within 8 hours account for 0,0014% of time. But I still don't know the time cost of index updates if I build the index to counter weight that. Or is there another approach?

Comment: If it were me, and this was the heaviest query in my app, I'd build the index and watch the metrics closely. Does overall performance go down? The index is going away. Judging from the percentages you posted, it is indeed very likely that adding the index would make performance worse.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am looking for a general formula for approximation whether to build an index or not, ideally without trial-and-error.

Comment: Ha, if you get one and it's working, let me know :)

Comment: I'd build the index, but I wouldn't necessarily trust mlab's recommendation! I've generally found that the recommendations about _when_ to build an index are good, but _which_ index to build aren't great. Even for your example -- I'd bet that an index with `myArray` first is going to perform way better.

Comment: I wouldn't look at % of total time -- the real issue with unindexed queries is the amount of load that they're putting on the cluster. If you don't have an index, you're likely spiking CPU, reading a ton of documents into memory, and doing work on those documents, etc -- it'll affect more queries than the one that you're actually looking at.

Comment: If an index isn't used often, that means that it won't be in wired tiger's cache so the main cost that you're paying is the extra update on writes! As long as you don't have too many indexes on a single collection, that cost isn't too bad

Comment: @willis Index efficiency should be increased when adding a constraint with high selectivity first, that is most likely *not* an array (depending on the number of possible array values vs. the 3 possible values of a boolean field), correct?

Comment: @willis Just a detail: I assume you mean you don't trust the *Slow Query Analyzer's recommendations* which are *auto-generated* and no substitute for knowing about how to construct an efficient index. However, the mLab support team is outstanding and in my experience I would rather consider their advice ;)

Comment: 1000% agree with mlab support team being outsanding! They're stellar

Comment: r.e. array "index efficiency" -- check out https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/ to check out how they get indexed. they're efficient!

Comment: for boolean values, it looks to me like somewhere in mongo 4.x they started indexing 3 values for boolean fields, but previously they would stop the index if a field wasn't defined. so if you're on 3.x & the boolean field isn't last you'll want to make sure it's actually defined.

Comment: @Manuel I would recommend you to build the index. Without it, this query would do a collection scan, which will push your working set out of the cache. After the query, it will take time to re-warm the cache with your working set again. If this performance penalty is not acceptable to you, then building the index is recommended.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha Interesting aspect; can you elaborate a bit on this? When does it make sense to build an index for a seemingly negligible query like this? Is the amount of 50k scanned docs the reason?

Comment: @Manuel it's probably too long a topic to discuss on this comment thread. It's more a topic for a blog post, tbh. A quick test is is this: warm up the cache by making random queries until it becomes fast (i.e. the query plan & working set is now in cache). Then do a totally different unindexed query that returns a lot of documents (similar to your query). Now try to go back to the earlier query pattern. Depending on hardware & memory size, you should see the earlier fast queries become slow again, and will gradually speed up again. This is what I mean by it got "pushed out of cache".